# Proving (cover) compactness implies completeness without using sequential compactness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

It is well known that for a subset $X$ in a metric space $M$, the following are equivalent:

(1) Every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

(2) Every sequence in $X$ has a subsequential limit in $X$.

(3) $X$ is complete and totally bounded.

In Marsden's ***Elementary Classical Analysis*** 2nd edition, one can see that the proof of "**3.1.3 Theorem**" shows (1) and (2) imply each other and that the proof of "**3.1.5 Theorem**" shows (2) and (3) imply each other.

Currently I am trying to prove (1) and (3) imply each other as a (self-studying) exercise.

Currently the most difficult part probably is proving (cover) compactness implies completeness. The uncomplete proof I have written is the following:

Assume for contradiction that $X$ is not complete. That is, assume there exist a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ in $X$ which (i) is a Cauchy sequence and (ii) does not converge in $X$. (ii) means: for every element $p$ in $X$ there exist $\epsilon_{p} > 0$ such that, for all $N\in\Bbb{N}$ there exists $N'>N$ such that $d(p_{N'},p)\geq\epsilon_{p}$. $\{B_{\epsilon_{p}}(p):p\in{X}\}$ is an open cover of $X$. By (1), there is a finite subcover $\{B_{\epsilon_{p_{1}}}(p_{1}),B_{\epsilon_{p_{2}}}(p_{2}),...,B_{\epsilon_{p_{\alpha}}}(p_{\alpha})\}$.

Now my intuitive idea is that: By (i) there can exists a sufficiently small open ball $B_{*}$ such that (iii) $B_{*}$ is contained in one of the finite subcover balls $B_{\epsilon_{p_{t}}}(p_{t})$ and (iv) for all suffitiently large $n$, $B_{*}$ contains all terms $x_{n}$ of the Cauchy sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. But $\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ does not converges to $p_{t}$ so there are infinitely many arbitrarily large $m$'s such that $x_{m}\notin{B_{\epsilon_{p_{t}}}(p_{t})}$ and hence $x_{m}\notin{B_{*}}$, which is a contradiction. Hence $X$ must be complete.

But I have tried very hard but still cannot turn my intuitive idea into a complete rigorous proof. Could someone please give me some instructions?

Comment: Use that a Cauchy sequence converges to all of its accumulation points, hence you can suppose that your Cauchy sequence has no accumulation point. And that means you get balls that contain $x_n$ for only finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply compactness to the balls $B_{\varepsilon_p/2}$ to get finitely many $p_1,\ldots,p_\alpha$ whose $\varepsilon_{p_i}/2$ balls cover the space.
Let $\varepsilon$ be the minimum of $\varepsilon_{p_1}/2,\ldots,\varepsilon_{p_\alpha}/2$. Since the sequence is Cauchy, for sufficiently large $N$, all but finitely many terms of the sequence are within $\varepsilon$ of $x_N$. Since $x_N$ must be in some ball $B_{\varepsilon_{p_i}/2}$, the triangle inequality gives that eventually all elements of the sequence are in $B_{\varepsilon_{p_i}}$. Contradiction!